# What is the differences between 2 events: Closing and Closed in WPF Apps?

Tags: c#, wpf

What is the differences between 2 events: `Closing` and `Closed` in **WPF** Apps?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [Closing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.closing?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) event raises immediately after `Close()` is called or user tried to close the window, and can be handled to cancel window closure.

The [Closed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.closed?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) raises after the window closed and cannot be cancelled.

**Example**

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to close the window",
        "Close?", MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel,
        MessageBoxImage.Question, MessageBoxResult.Cancel) != MessageBoxResult.Yes)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}

private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Window closed.");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The convention in .NET is that events in present tense, such as `Closing`, are raised before the event trigger is executed, often allowing you to cancel the execution (in this case, prevent closing). Events in the past tense, such as `Closed`, are raised after the trigger has executed, allowing you to perform cleanup operations or otherwise respond to it.